# nonlinear system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Could you help me to solve the following system of  $3$ equations and $3$ variables?

$$\left\{\begin{array} {lllll}
2x+y+z=0\\
x-z-\sin y=0\\
x-y+\sin z=0\\
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first equation, you can eliminate $x=-\frac{1}{2} (y+z)$; so now the second equation becomes $$y+2 \sin (y)+3 z=0$$ from which $z=-\frac{1}{3} (y+2 \sin (y))$. Replacing in the third, $$4 y-\sin (y)+3 \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} (y+2 \sin (y))\right)=0$$ for which I doubt that you could find an explicit solution except $??$ (what you could have guessed by inspection).

I am sure that you can take from here.

**Edit**

The problem would have been much more interesting using as  third equation $$x-y+\cos(z)=0$$ Try to play with it; it is interesting. You just need to replace $3\sin(.)$ by  $3\cos(.)$

Answer (score 1):

There is one fairly simple solution to start with.

Use the first equation to eliminate $x$ from the other two equations.
Now the second equation gives you $z$ as a function of $y$.  Plug that into the third equation, and you get a single equation for $y$.
Plot this equation using Wolfram Alpha, or your calculator, to estimate the solutions.

Comment: You are too fast for the old man ! I am typing the same !! Cheers